# Reduce RAM consumption of structure in C

Tags: c, embedded

I'm currently developing a firmware for a microcontroller. I'm using the following structure in my code:

```
struct sub
{
uint16_t a1;
uint16_t a2;
uint16_t a3;
uint16_t a4;
uint16_t a5;
uint16_t a6;
uint16_t a7;
uint16_t a8;
uint8_t a9;
uint8_t a10;
};

struct state
{
struct sub sub1;
struct sub sub2;
struct sub sub3;
struct sub sub4;
};


typedef struct
{
uint16_t c1;
uint16_t c2;
uint16_t c3;
uint16_t c4;
struct state state1;
struct state state2;
struct state state3;
struct state state4;
struct state state5;
struct state state6;
struct state state7;
struct state state8;
} status
```

So, the hierarchy is status, state and sub.
Does anybody of you see a possibility to reduce the RAM size needed by this structure? Currently, it needs approximately twice the space all variables would need individually if they were not stored in a structure.

Comment: it would probably depend on the achitecture of your microcontroller (for word alignment)

Comment: Have a look at structure packing and padding, it is very helpful (but it doesn't perform miracles).

Comment: On my machine, `sizeof(status)` is 584. This is exactly the result of `sizeof(sub)` (18) * 4 * 8 + 4*2, so the statement "*Currently, it needs approximately twice the space all variables would need individually if they were not stored in a structure*" is simply incorrect. What is the actual size of the `status` on your machine?

Comment: _"twice the space all variables would need individually"_ : If that is true, it would suggest that the compiler is generating 32bit alignment, which may or may not be the case.  Options for "packing" a structure are compiler/target dependent.  On some targets, packing a structure may generate additional access code if unaligned access is not supported.  Saving RAM usage is generally a high-level application design issue rather then a code-level "trick".  For example, what is teh range of values stored in each member?  Do they need to be 16 bit?  Could you use bitfields for example?

Comment: Questions about optimization can't be answered without knowing the specific system and compiler used.

Comment: @Clifford: The range of all a1 - a8 is 0 - 1023.

Comment: @Peter123 So use 10 bit bitfields and structure packing, but be aware that member access will probably generate larger code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__attribute__((packed))` for your structure, that will change the padding and then reduce the RAM needed for your structure

Edit:

This doesn't works with all compilers, but the idea you have to remember is `padding`, you can do it naturally by sorting your variables by their types.

Ex:

```
struct s_structure1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    char d;
    float e;
}

struct s_structure2 {
    int a;
    char c;
    int b;
    float e;
    char d;
}
```

size of s_structure1 in bytes : 16

size of s_structure2 in bytes : 20

Comment: It's far from obvious why padding would create a struct twice as big anyway.

Comment: "This only works with gcc compiler..." `__attribute__((packed))` works on several compilers, not only GCC (for instance, keil compiler, http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124980173.htm)

Comment: I think the answer could easily be made more generic by mentioning the idea of packing and referring to the GCC or pragma methods of specifying it.  That would at least give search engine terms to guide somebody to further info.

Comment: As you can see in the "Edit", i said that `padding` is the important idea to remember